# Super-class reference variable to a sub-class object accesses the subclass's attribute instead of the super's

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

In my code, I have 3 classes:
class `A`

```java
public class A {
    int x = 1;
    static double y = 3.0;
    public A() {
    x = (int)y;
    }
    public A(int x) {
    this .x = this . getX () + x;
    }
    int getX () {
    return this .x;
    }
    public void f( float z) {
    y *= z;
    }
}
```

class `B`, which extends `A`

```java
public class B extends A {
    int x = 7;
    public B(int x) {
    super (x);
    this .x = x;
    }
    public B() {
    this .y += 1.0;
    }
    int getX () {
    return this .x;
    }
    public void f( long z) {
    y += z;
    }
    public void f( double z) {
    y -= z;
    }
}
```

and class `M`, which includes the `main` function

```java
public class M {
    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        A a1 = new A();
        System .out. println (a1.x + " " + A.y); // OUT: [ ] [ ]
        B b1 = new B();
        System .out. println (b1.x + " " + A.y); // OUT: [ ] [ ]
        System .out. println ((( A)b1 ).x); // OUT: [ ]
        A ab = new B (5);
        System .out. println (ab.x + " " + A.y); // OUT: [ ] [ ]
        System .out. println ((( A)ab ).x); // OUT: [ ]
        A.y = 5.0;
        b1.f (2.0f);
        System .out. println (A.y); // OUT: [ ]
        ab.f (5);
        System .out. println (A.y); // OUT: [ ]
        }
}
```

Every called function in the `main` method behaves as expected except for the following two:

```java
        A ab = new B (5);
        System .out. println (ab.x + " " + A.y); // OUT: [ ] [ ]
        System .out. println ((( A)ab ).x); // OUT: [ ]
```

which gives

```
5 4.0
5
```

as output, while I expect it to give

```
6 4.0
6
```

Now, as far I understand, upon creating a new object of type `B`, which is referred to by the reference variable `ab` of type `A`, and after invoking the right constructors, the variable `x` in the super-class should have the value of `6`, while the other `x` in the sub-class equals `5`.

If this is right, then, shouldn't `ab.x` refer to the `x` in the super-class, which equals `6`, since attributes and static methods (in contrary to non-static methods) are dealt with in compile time, which means that the `println` method should print the variable, within the same class as the reference variable type?

And in case of `(( A)ab ).x)` shouldn't the `x` in class `B` be invisible after casting `ab`?

I'd be thankful if you can guide me through, why this is happening.

Comment: `this .x = this . getX () + x;` in `A` constructor uses the overridden function `getX` from `B`, that's the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement `this.x = this.getX() + x; in A constructor`will call `getX from B` so the variable x in the super-class will have the value of `5` not `6`.

So when you call this statement

```
A ab = new B (5);
```

Flow will be

It will call parameterized constructor in `class B`, then it will encounter `super(x)` statement, so it will call parameterized constructor in `class A` where you have this statement `this.x = this.getX() + x;` which will call `getX()` of `class B` which will return `this.x` ( here x value be returned as `0`) so the final value of `this.x = this.getX() + x;` is (0+5 = 5), and this.x will have a final value of 5. This way in both `class A` and `class B` variable `x` value will be 5.

That is why your following statements are returning

```
System .out. println (ab.x + " " + A.y); // OUT: [5] [3.0]
System .out. println ((( A)ab ).x); // OUT: [5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got it. There is only thing, which I don' t understand yet; why would `this.getX()` return `0`? doesn't the `x` in `class B` equal 7?

Comment: Or does it have a default value of `0` since it's an instance variable and the constructor block isn't completely executed yet? In this case, does this mean that instance variables are created first, given default values, then the right constructor block is executed, and after that the stated value will be assigned to the variable, even if this value isn't inside the constructor block?

Comment: @Mohamed Fathy, yes you are right , this.getX(), here this will refer to the object of class B and B instance has value of x as 0, since till this point no value has been assigned to x of class B